# How to retrieve error code and message when distributed tx fails? (MS DTC)

Tags: sql-server-2008, try-catch, msdtc, distributed-transactions, xact-abort

We have got a stored procedure that starts a distributed transaction via a linked server with different MS SQL 2008 databases.

We use

```
  SET XACT_ABORT ON;
```

and also

```
  BEGIN TRY / CATCH blocks
```

around the transaction to catch any errors and return the error code & message back to the calling client.

However, when a command inside the distributed transaction fails, it seems that the MS DTC is taking over control and our catch block can't rollback "gracefully" and return the error message etc. Instead an error is raised: The Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has cancelled the distributed transaction. (Error 1206).

Is there any way that such a distributed tx error is caught by a catch block?

Comment: I think I found the answer, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546781/check-contraint-bypassing-catch-block-in-distributed-transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ---UPDATE---

Looks like this is a known issue and Microsoft are not going to fix it:
http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/414969/uncatchable-error-when-distributed-transaction-is-aborted

There is a workaround but uses SSIS to call the SP:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlnetfx/thread/02e43cad-ac11-45fa-9281-6b4959929be7

---

You should be able to use XACT_STATE() to rollback the transaction and a RAISERROR coupled with @@ERROR to give you more details

> ```
>   SET NOCOUNT ON
>   SET XACT_ABORT ON
>           BEGIN TRY
>       BEGIN TRANSACTION
> ```

..code goes here

> ```
>   COMMIT TRANSACTION;
> ```
>
> END TRY
>     BEGIN CATCH
>
> ```
>   DECLARE @errormsg VARCHAR(MAX)
>   SET @errormsg = @@ERROR
>
>   -- Test XACT_STATE:
>       -- If 1, the transaction is committable.
>       -- If -1, the transaction is uncommittable and should 
>       --     be rolled back.
>       -- XACT_STATE = 0 means that there is no transaction and
>       --     a commit or rollback operation would generate an error.
>
>   -- Test whether the transaction is uncommittable.
>   IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
>   BEGIN
>       ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
>   END;
>
>   -- Test whether the transaction is committable.
>   IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1
>   BEGIN
>       COMMIT TRANSACTION;   
>   END;
>
>   RAISERROR(@errormsg, 16, 1)
> ```
>
> END CATCH

Comment: The second Rollback command should be a commit, shouldn't it? Probably just a typo? But the catch block still isn't really executed, the MS DTC is still taking over. E.g. when inserting print statements before the rollback / commit command, nothing gets printed. Also, I don't see my error message that is raised via the RAISEERROR command, but the generic MS DTC error message as copied in my OP.